# Dragging a component to a specific target in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuedraggable

I am using `vuedraggable` to allow users to drag items from one list to another. Here is what it looks like currently:

[image: two lists]

The default functionality of `vuedraggable` is to insert the source element into the destination list

[image: default drop]

However, I would like to treat the destination list as a drop placeholder so that the source item would highlight the target on hover, and replace it on drop like so:

[image: default drag]

Is there a way to achieve this effect using `vuedraggable` or using another similar component?